# OpenCart Fault Uncaught Error: Class 'Controllerextensiontotalaffiliate'

Tags: php, error-handling, opencart, opencart2.x

Im currently got this issue on our basket page, but can't seem to work out what is causing it:

I have done the following:

Disabled vQmod
Disabled Mods in vQmod
Tried disabling anything to do with affliates.

Im stuck with ideas.

```
[02-Apr-2020 15:37:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Controllerextensiontotalaffiliate' not found in /home/mvhwbpqz/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_system_engine_action.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mvhwbpqz/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_system_engine_loader.php(31): Action->execute(Object(Registry), Array)
#1 /home/mvhwbpqz/public_html/catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php(246): Loader->controller('extension/total...')
#2 /home/mvhwbpqz/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_system_engine_action.php(51): ControllerCheckoutCart->index()
#3 /home/mvhwbpqz/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/router.php(25): Action->execute(Object(Registry))
#4 /home/mvhwbpqz/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_system_engine_action.php(51): ControllerStartupRouter->index()
#5 /home/mvhwbpqz/public_html/system/engine/front.php(34): Action->execute(Object(Registry))
#6 /home/mvhwbpqz/public_html/system/engine/front.php(29): Front->execute(Object(Action))
#7 /home/mv in /home/mvhwbpqz/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_system_engine_action.php on line 43
```

Code for the action File

```
<?php
class Action {
    private $id;
    private $route;
    private $method = 'index';

    public function __construct($route) {
        $this->id = $route;

        $parts = explode('/', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\/]/', '', (string)$route));

        // Break apart the route
        while ($parts) {
            $file = DIR_APPLICATION . 'controller/' . implode('/', $parts) . '.php';

            if (is_file($file)) {
                $this->route = implode('/', $parts);        

                break;
            } else {
                $this->method = array_pop($parts);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function execute($registry, array $args = array()) {
        // Stop any magical methods being called
        if (substr($this->method, 0, 2) == '__') {
            return new \Exception('Error: Calls to magic methods are not allowed!');
        }

        $file = DIR_APPLICATION . 'controller/' . $this->route . '.php';        
        $class = 'Controller' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $this->route);

        // Initialize the class
        if (is_file($file)) {
            include_once(\VQMod::modCheck(modification($file), $file));

            $controller = new $class($registry);
        } else {
            return new \Exception('Error: Could not call ' . $this->route . '/' . $this->method . '!');
        }

        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);

        if ($reflection->hasMethod($this->method) && $reflection->getMethod($this->method)->getNumberOfRequiredParameters() <= count($args)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($controller, $this->method), $args);
        } else {
            return new \Exception('Error: Could not call ' . $this->route . '/' . $this->method . '!');
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see its loading all controllers, but i tried renaming the affliates controller to see if that would help but didn't.

Kinda lost what to try now.

Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 0):

If you are disabling vQmod - you shouldn't get an error via vqcache files. If you disabling vq mods - clear vq cache after that. Have you done it?

Although you need to inspect every vQmod modification file to find, which one is adding or requiring 'Controllerextensiontotalaffiliate'.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a core file edited, due to the old web developers, so we removed it as not needed. Now the site works perfectly. Just wish people wouldnt edit the core files.